How Can there be a Gravitational Potential when there is NO Gravitational Field?
How does it make any logic that there exist a potential when there is no net field
for example when we have a Hollow Sphere with mass we can find out the the gravitational *potential inside the sphere which comes out to be $(-GM/R)$ where $G$ is universal gravitational constant, $M$ is mass of the hollow sphere and $R$ is the radius.
We know that for a hollow sphere there is no net gravitational field inside the sphere but there some how exist a potential inside the sphere
I think that using the idea that as no field is there no potential should be there
I think that i have some major conseptual misunderstanding
I keep trying to find the error in my way of thinking but i still keep coming back to where i started i even tried using
V=integration of E.dr
E is zero V should be zero
whats wrong here?

The potential at a point $P$ is $-GM/R$ where $R$ is the radius of the entire sphere, not just the distance of $P$ from the center.   Therefore $-GM/R$ does not depend on $P$.

Derivative of a constant is 0...

Why is this closed for being homework-like? This is actually a really good question. The answer comes down to the fact that Newton's shell theorem only applies outside the sphere, leading to regular gravity, while on the inside, integrating over the sphere gives you a net force of zero.

You would be right, if you took your reference, at the center of the sphere, to be at a potential of 0. Throughout the sphere, you have a constant potential, which would remain 0.
Generally, we take $r=\infty$ to be our reference point, where $V=0$, therefore we get some non-zero value of potential at the center of the sphere.
Remember, potential is always relative, so be wary of the limits of your integral. The usual integral is:
$$\int_0^{V}dV=\int_{\infty}^{r}\frac{Gm}{r^2}dr
$$
We get this as potential at $r=\infty$ is taken as 0, and potential at some $r$ is some $V$.
